# Hyperledger fabric configtxgen proto: Marshal called with nil

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create genesis block in hyperledger fabric 2.3 using configtxgen. Please find the profile details I am using to create the gensis block in configtx.yaml file.

```
---
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7051
            - orderer2.example.com:7052
            - orderer3.example.com:7053
            - orderer4.example.com:7054

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        Policies: &Org1Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 8051

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 9051
```

## CAPABILITIES

```
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true
```

## APPLICATION

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "CheckCommitReadiness" function
        _lifecycle/CheckCommitReadiness: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "CommitChaincodeDefinition" function
        _lifecycle/CommitChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "QueryChaincodeDefinition" function
        _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "QueryChaincodeDefinitions" function
        _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinitions: /Channel/Application/Writers

        #---Lifecycle System Chaincode (lscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getid" function
        lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getdepspec" function
        lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getccdata" function
        lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL Policy for lscc's "getchaincodes" function
        lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Query System Chaincode (qscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetChainInfo" function
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByNumber" function
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's  "GetBlockByHash" function
        qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetTransactionByID" function
        qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByTxID" function
        qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Configuration System Chaincode (cscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigBlock" function
        cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetChannelConfig" function
        cscc/GetChannelConfig: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Miscellaneous peer function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for invoking chaincodes on peer
        peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for chaincode to chaincode invocation
        peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Writers

        #---Events resource to policy mapping for access control###---#

        # ACL policy for sending block events
        event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for sending filtered block events
        event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

    # Organizations lists the orgs participating on the application side of the
    # network.
    Organizations:

    Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the application level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

## ORDERER

```
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7051
        - orderer2.example.com:7052
        - orderer3.example.com:7053
        - orderer4.example.com:7054
        - orderer5.example.com:7055

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7051
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer2.example.com
          Port: 7052
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer3.example.com
          Port: 7053
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer4.example.com
          Port: 7054
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer5.example.com
          Port: 7055
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

    # Capabilities describes the orderer level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities
```

## CHANNEL

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
```

## PROFILES

```
Profiles:    
    SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            Organizations:
                - <<: *Org1
                  Policies:
                      <<: *Org1Policies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('Org1.member')"
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *Org1
                  Policies:
                      <<: *Org1Policies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('Org1.member')"
```

But, when I try to create the genesis file with the command.

```
configtxgen -profile SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft -outputBlock genesis_block.pb -channelID channel1
```

I am getting below error

```
 [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 005 proto: Marshal called with nil
panic: proto: Marshal called with nil [recovered]
        panic: proto: Marshal called with nil
```

Comment: If configtxgen is wrong, there are three things to check in your situation. **First**, it is necessary to check whether the version of configtxgen is compatible with the Fabric2.3 version. **Second**  It seems that SampleOrg has been changed to Org1, and you need information about whether the following values are set correctly. `&ChannelDefaults` `&OrdererDefaults` `&Org1` `&Org1Policies` `&ApplicationDefaults`

Comment: **Finally** You need to make sure that msp(path) in your configtx.yaml file exists and matches. If it is run on the host pc, enter the absolute path of msp on the host pc. If it is run on the fabric-tools docker, run msp by volume mounting or copy&paste, and then write the path to configtx.yaml

Comment: @myeongkilkim Thank for the reply, I have updated the question with other details of the configtx.yaml file. I am using the configtxgen with version 2.3.0 . I have also checked the path to the MSP of each org, they are also correct. Can you please let me know if there is anything i need to change in the configtx.yaml ?

Comment: There is no singularity except that orderer5 is missing in the orderer's OrdererEndpoints. In the case of this error, i have a record of troubleshooting when crypto-config was not found in the MSP Path before. Could you change `MSPDir` `ClientTLSCert` `ServerTLSCert`  to an absolute path rather than a relative path?

Comment: @myeongkilkim Thank you pointing out about orderer5. I have updated the orderer5 endpoint and also used the absolute path for the MSPDir, ClientTLSCert and ServerTLSCert. Unfortunately, I face the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment since the reputation is low
so now..., I got the same error,so I just check the "crypto-config" folder and found out that I don't have enough **certificates**

so I checked the "**docker-compose.yaml**" file and  another file (I have a custom structure in my folders) that is responisible in creating certificates.And there I found out I made a wrong entering of **PORT** number for one of the organizations which is not matching with the **PORT** number of the organization mentioned in "**docker-compose.yaml**".

So, I corrected it, made the file run again, got the created enough certificates,now its fine.

this worked for me, let me know if you already got any other solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by regenerating users and peers crypto credentials

exp if using crytpogen :

```
cryptogen generate --config=org3-crypto.yaml --output="../organizations"
```

in case of CA (test-network) just run `./network down`